# How to update multiple rows and columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, data-manipulation

I want to update multiple rows and columns in a CSV file, using `pandas`

I've tried using `iterrows()` method but it only works on a single column.

here is the logic I want to apply for multiple rows and columns:

```py
if(value < mean):
  value += std_dev
else:
  value -= std_dev
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: Check apply - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: You should add a small example dataset.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way of doing it,

Consider your data is like this:

```
  price strings value
0     1       A     a
1     2       B     b
2     3       C     c
3     4       D     d
4     5       E     f
```

Now lets make `strings` column as the index:

```
df.set_index('strings', inplace='True')

#Result
        price value
strings
A           1     a
B           2     b
C           3     c
D           4     d
E           5     f
```

Now set the values of rows `C, D, E` as `0`

```
df.loc[['C', 'D','E']] = 0

#Result
        price value
strings
A           1     a
B           2     b
C           0     0
D           0     0
E           0     0
```

or you can do more precisely

```
df.loc[df.strings.isin(["C", "D", "E"]), df.columns.difference(["strings"])] = 0
df
Out[82]: 
  price strings value
0     1       A     a
1     2       B     b
2     0       C     0
3     0       D     0
4     0       E     0
```